# TypeScript type canvas context property setter

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas

I have a class which wraps an HTML5 canvas element and I would like to type a function that can be used to set mutable properties on the context:

```
class MyContext {
  container: HTMLDivElement;
  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  constructor(container: HTMLDivElement) {
    this.container = container;
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d")!;
    container.appendChild(this.canvas);
  }

  setProps(props: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(props)) {
      this.context[k] = v; // Error:  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.
    }
    return this
  }
}
```

Is there any way to type `props` correctly so I can set all of the mutable properties? In similar situations, I tend to use a helper function that correctly types key-value pairs instead of `Object.entries()`, i.e.:

```
function entries<T extends Record<PropertyKey, any>>(object: T) {
  return Object.entries(object) as {
    [key in keyof T]: [key, T[key]];
  }[keyof T][];
}
```

However, that doesn't really help here since `CanvasRenderingContext2D` contains readonly properties.